# ubuntu 10.04 span window across workspaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, workspace

I'm using an old server machine as a linux box desktop, and as such I have a lot of power but not a lot of display options.  I cannot increase my resolution past 800x600 and recently this has become just to small.

I have mostly been able to workaround windows being to large for a workspace by moving them with the alt key, but I would like to use something a little more versatile.  My plan is to have a setup where I can open a windows (say firefox) on the top-left workspace and then resize it so that it fills four workspaces in an emulated "wall of monitors" fashion.  I already have my workspaces arranged like this, but I am not seeing any options for allowing programs/windows to exist on more than one workspace at a time,

I know that what I am trying to accomplish is possible (or was at some point in time) because when I google my solution pages appear with people trying to do the opposite (windows already appear on more than one workspace and they dislike it).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

metacity doesn't allow this, but other window managers might. I do remember that I had windows crossing workspaces at one point, but this was quite long ago so I'm not certain which WM it was (might have been FVWM2).